# polymorphic to address an event to companies, departments, employeers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I hope the issue is not duplicated, I have been looking at stackoverflow but could not find any similar issue so far. Basically I want to create an event addressed to (all company, or all department, or one or many  employees...)

My models look like:

```
class Event 
  has_many :recipients
end;

class Recipients
  belongs_to: event
  belongs_to :addresseeable, polymorphic: true  
end 

class Companies
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable  
end

class Departments
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable
end

class Employees
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable 
end
```

My doubt is actually in the client side how to make a good form to create and update an event. Are there any special multiples select suitable in this case or maybe another way? Giving that if I select one company, I cant select their departments neither employees, and if I select one department I can't select heir employees.

My solution for now:

---

I created a 3 multiple selects (using chosen plugin) which handle a dynamic selections to choose companies, departments, or employees. In the next pictures, I selected first Company1, then Department1, then the 3 employees, when I click "Add recipients" I want to add only the 3 employees to the table.

Another example, if I selected Company1, then Department1 without selecting any employee, when I click "Add recipients" it must add Department1 to the table. Therefore, it adds always the elements selected in the last multiple select.

[image]

my form code is:

```
<%= form_for @event, html: { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Companies</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <%= select_tag "", options_for_select(@companies), { :multiple => true, :class => "chosen", :style => "width:50%;", :id => "companies_select" } %>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="departments_group" class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departments</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select id="departments_select" style="width:50%;" multiple class="chosen">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="employees_group" class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employees</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select id="employees_select" style="width:50%;" multiple class="chosen">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>


<%= link_to_add_new_fields "Add Recipients", f, :recipients %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="recioients" class="table table-bordered table-striped mg-t datatable editable-datatable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">Id</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">Type</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">Deleted</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                    <%= f.fields_for :recipients do |recipient_builder| %>
                      <%= render 'recipient_fields', f: recipient_builder %>
                    <% end %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /col-md-9 -->
</div>
<!-- /row -->


<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :title %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Partial file _recipient_fields.html.erb

```
<tr>
 <td style="display:none;"><%= f.hidden_field :addresseeable_id %></td>
 <td style="display:none;"><%= f.hidden_field :addresseeable_type %></td>
 <td><%= content_tag :name %></td>
 <td style="display:none;"><%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %></td>
 <td><%= link_to "Delete Recipient", '#', class: "remove_recipient" %></td>
</tr>
```

I am actually stuck here in the helper method and scripts to build many object when clicking the "Add Recipients" button

```
def link_to_add_new_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
      id = new_object.object_id
      fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
      end
      link_to(name, '#', class: "add_new_recipients btn btn-primary btn-sm", data: {id: id, type: "", fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Scripts:

```
$('form').on 'change', '#companies_select', (event) ->
    $.ajax
        url: "/events/get_departments"
        type: "GET"
        dataType: "script"
        data: company_id: $('#companies_select option:selected:last').val()
  $('#departments_group').show()
  $('#departments_select').empty()


$('form').on 'change', "#departments_select", (event) ->
    $.ajax
        url: "/events/get_employees"
        type: "GET"
        dataType: "script"
        data: department_id: $('#departments_select option:selected:last').val()
  $('#employees_group').show()
  $('#employees_select').empty()

 $('form').on 'click', '.remove_recipient', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('tr').hide()
    event.preventDefault()


 $('form').on 'click', '.add_new_recipients', (event) ->
    if $('#employees_select option:selected').length() > 0
      $('#employees_select option:selected').each (i, selected) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_type'), "User")
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_id'), $(selected).val())
        $(this).closest('tr').after($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))

    else if $('#departments_select option:selected').length() > 0
      $('#departments_select option:selected').each (i, selected) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_type'), "Department")
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_id'), $(selected).val())
        $(this).closest('tr').after($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))

    else if $('#companies_select option:selected').length() > 0
      $('#companies_select option:selected').each (i, selected) ->
        if $(selected).text() == "All departments"
          time = new Date().getTime()
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_type'), "Company")
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_id'), $(selected).val())
          $(this).closest('tr').after($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
        else
          time = new Date().getTime()
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_type'), "Department")
          regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('addresseeable_id'), $(selected).val())
          $(this).closest('tr').after($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))

    event.preventDefault()
```

Here actually I am not sure if I am doing it well, after the "Add recipients" button it must build several object for :recipients fields. Any suggestions how to solve it this way?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails views, it is fairly simple

```
class Event 
  has_many :recipients
  accept_nested_attributes_for :recipients
end;

class Recipients
  belongs_to: event
  belongs_to :addresseeable, polymorphic: true  
end 

class Companies
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable  
end

class Departments
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable
end

class Employees
  has_many :Recipients, as: :addresseeable 
end
```

Now, use [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) to make nested forms of recepients(with addresseeable
_type, addresseeable_id)

In controller

```
def create
  @event = Event.create(params[:event])
end
```

Edit - Its just a test code, so you might have to tweak a little to get it work.

Controller code

```
def new
  @event = @event.new
  2.times { @event.recipients.build }
end
```

To add a sample form :-

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @event.recipients do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.select :addresseeable_type, [['Companies','Companies'], ['Departments','Departments'], ['Employees','Employess']], {}, { class: 'address-type' } do %>
  <%= ff.select :addresseeable_id do %>
    <% Recipients.all.each do |r|
      <%= content_tag(:option, r.addresseeable.name, value: r.addresseeable_id, class: "address-option #{ r.addresseeable_type }") %>
    <% end  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Do some JavaScript, to handle the fact that we only need to show those options that correspond to the addresseeable_type

```
$(function() {
  $('.address-type').on('change', function() {
    $(this).find('.address-option').hide()
    $(this).find('.' + $(this).val()).show()
  });
});
```

Comment: sahilbathla could you write a piece of code of the form! I don't see which types must take the fields addresseeable_type and addresseeable_id.

Comment: Well, I did add a sample code so that you get an idea, I didn't run it but it should give you the idea of how to proceed

Comment: Thanks sahibathla for posting your code, btw why you're fetching all recipients into the form "Recipients.all.each"? I edited the body post, actually I want that I can select (all, none, one or some)companies, the same for departments and employees. But if I select one company I cannot select their departments and their employees. And if I select one department I cannot select their employees.

Comment: Made some changes, Recipients.all.each is used to fetch all the addresseeables i.e All companies, departments and employees, because you want to create a recepient and assign in it one of them. As for the logic to either choose company or department or employee, you can fiddle with the jQUery code

Comment: I see what you mean, it helped a lot to understand how must send the data to the controller  using polymorphic, But actually when having thousands of employees in a company it is not nice to show all of them in the custom select. I posted a solution how I handled a dynamic selection to choose recipients step by step but still stuck how to build many :recipients fields in one time.